# How to handle external service failure in Open-Uri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

In my Rails app I am trying to fetch a number of currency exchange rates from an external service and store them in the cache:

```
require 'open-uri'

module ExchangeRate

  def self.all
    Rails.cache.fetch("exchange_rates", :expires_in => 24.hours) { load_all }
  end

  private

    def self.load_all
      hashes = {}
      CURRENCIES.each do |currency|
        begin
          hash = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{currency}")).read) #what if not available?
          hashes[currency] = hash["rates"]
        rescue Timeout::Error
          puts "Timeout"
        rescue OpenURI::Error => e
          puts e.message
        end
      end
      hashes
    end

end
```

This works great in development but I am worried about the production environment. How can I prevent the whole thing from being cached if the external service is not available? How can I ensure `ExchangeRate.all` always contains data, even if it's old and can't be updated due to an external service failure?

I tried to add some basic error handling but I'm afraid it's not enough.

Comment: You might for example keep another cache of "exchange_rates_backup" that would not expire and that would be set each time the external service would be successfully read. Then this "backup" cache might be used in the `all` method as a backup.

Comment: You could rely on a custom table within your database. If `load_all` fails, you could use the records from your own table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about your external service not being reliable enough to keep up with caching every 24 hours, then you should disable the auto cache expiration, let users work with old data, and set up some kind of notification system to tell you if the `load_all` fails.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Assume ExchangeRate.all always returns a cached copy, with no expiration (this will return `nil` if no cache is found):

   ```
   module ExchangeRate
     def self.all
       rates = Rails.cache.fetch("exchange_rates")
       UpdateCurrenciesJob.perform_later if rates.nil?
       rates
     end
   end
   ```
2. Create an ActiveJob that handles the updates on a regular basis:

   ```
   class UpdateCurrenciesJob < ApplicationJob
     queue_as :default

     def perform(*_args)
       hashes = {}
       CURRENCIES.each do |currency|
         begin
           hash = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{currency}")).read) # what if not available?
           hashes[currency] = hash['rates'].merge('updated_at' => Time.current)
         rescue Timeout::Error
           puts 'Timeout'
         rescue OpenURI::Error => e
           puts e.message
         end

         if hashes[currency].blank? || hashes[currency]['updated_at'] < Time.current - 24.hours
           # send a mail saying "this currency hasn't been updated"
         end
       end

       Rails.cache.write('exchange_rates', hashes)
     end
   end
   ```
3. Set the job up to run every few hours (4, 8, 12, less than 24). This way, the currencies will load in the background, the clients will always have data, and you will always know if currencies aren't working.